# HTML table to Excel, Browser Stucks

Tags: javascript, html

I have downloaded Javascript function for converting HTML table to excel. It will convert all table in the page to excel, Actually I need only a specific table to be converted to excel that also in Button Click. But the downloaded javascript codes executing Page load itself. Can somebody guide me how to make it as function and also for particular table ( given table id )

```
    <table id="testTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>ACP</th>
                <th>OEMCP</th>
                <th>Unix<br>
                    NT 3.1</th>
                <th>Unix<br>
                    NT 3.51</th>
                <th>Unix<br>
                    95</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <table id="testTable1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>ACP</th>
                <th>OEMCP</th>
                <th>Windows<br>
                    NT 3.1</th>
                <th>Windows<br>
                    NT 3.51</th>
                <th>Windows<br>
                    95</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function(){
      var cache = {};

      this.tmpl = function tmpl(str, data){
        // Figure out if we're getting a template, or if we need to
        // load the template - and be sure to cache the result.
        var fn = !/\W/.test(str) ?
          cache[str] = cache[str] ||
            tmpl(document.getElementById(str).innerHTML) :

          // Generate a reusable function that will serve as a template
          // generator (and which will be cached).
          new Function("obj",
            "var p=[],print=function(){p.push.apply(p,arguments);};" +

            // Introduce the data as local variables using with(){}
            "with(obj){p.push('" +

            // Convert the template into pure JavaScript
            str.replace(/[\r\t\n]/g, " ")
                  .split("{{").join("\t")
                  .replace(/((^|}})[^\t]*)'/g, "$1\r")
                  .replace(/\t=(.*?)}}/g, "',$1,'")
                  .split("\t").join("');")
                  .split("}}").join("p.push('")
                  .split("\r").join("\\'")
                  + "');}return p.join('');");

        // Provide some basic currying to the user
        return data ? fn( data ) : fn;
      };
    })();

    var tableToExcel = (function() {
        var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
            template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{{=worksheet}}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body>{{for(var i=0; i<tables.length;i++){ }}<table>{{=tables[i]}}</table>{{ } }}</body></html>',    
        base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) },
        format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
        return function(tableList, name) {
            if (!tableList.length>0 && !tableList[0].nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
            var tables = [];
            for(var i=0; i<tableList.length; i++){
              tables.push(tableList[i].innerHTML);
            }
            var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', tables: tables};
            window.location.href = uri + base64(tmpl(template, ctx))
        }
    })();        
    tableToExcel(document.getElementsByTagName("table"),"one");
    </script>
```

From the above code, I need only "testTable" excel export. Also when I executing this javascript, browser get stucks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tableToExcel(document.getElementsByTagName("table"),"one");`

this is the key line for you!

you give it a table list and a name for your new worksheet.

if you want only one:

```
function expTable(tbl)
{
     var tables = [];
     tables.push(tbl);
     tableToExcel(tables,"myTableExcelWorkbook");
}
```

run it using `expTable(document.getElementById(tableId));`

Comment: I have tried by changing getElementById("testTable") . But Its not working

Comment: because it require a List of elements, not Element

Comment: Thanks, It works. But still my browses ( Mozilla Firefox 22) stuck when I executing the script. After a minute it showing error like stop script

Comment: Specifically FireFox?  or others like Chrome/IE/Safari ?

Comment: Sorry, I think It due to my system issue, I have checked it in frnds system. It works fine. Thanks for ur help....

Comment: np. happy to have helped.